# spark sql cast function creates column with NULLS

Tags: scala, casting, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe and schema in Spark

```
val df = spark.read.options(Map("header"-> "true")).csv("path")

scala> df show()

+-------+-------+-----+
|   user|  topic| hits|
+-------+-------+-----+
|     om|  scala|  120|
| daniel|  spark|   80|
|3754978|  spark|    1|
+-------+-------+-----+

scala> df printSchema

root
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |--  topic: string (nullable = true)
 |--  hits: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to change the column hits to integer

I tried this:

```
scala>    df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
    val dfNew = spark.sql("select *, cast('hist' as integer) as hist2 from test")

scala> dfNew.printSchema

root
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |--  topic: string (nullable = true)
 |--  hits: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hist2: integer (nullable = true)
```

but when I print the dataframe the column hist 2 is filled with NULLS

```
scala> dfNew show()

+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|   user|  topic| hits|hist2|
+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|     om|  scala|  120| null|
| daniel|  spark|   80| null|
|3754978|  spark|    1| null|
+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

I also tried this:

```
scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("hitsTmp",
df.hits.cast(IntegerType)).drop("hits"
).withColumnRenamed("hitsTmp", "hits")
```

and got this:

```
<console>:26: error: value hits is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFram
e
```

Also tried this:

```
scala> val df2 = df.selectExpr ("user","topic","cast(hits as int) hits")

and got this:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`topic`' given input col
umns: [user,  topic,  hits]; line 1 pos 0;
'Project [user#0, 'topic, cast('hits as int) AS hits#22]
+- Relation[user#0, topic#1, hits#2] csv
```

with

```
 scala> val df2 = df.selectExpr ("cast(hits as int) hits")
```

I get similar error.

Any help will be appreciated. I know this question has been addressed before but I tried 3 different approaches (published here) and none is working.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.0

Answer (score 3):

How do we let the spark cast throw an exception instead of generating all the null values?
Do I have to calculate the total number of null values before & after the cast in order to see if the cast is actually successful?

This post [How to test datatype conversion during casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496975/how-to-test-datatype-conversion-during-casting) is doing that. I wonder if there is a better solution here.

Comment: Hi Zach, ran into this and wanted Spark to throw an exception. Any idea if it is still impossible?

Comment: i didn't end up counting the null values. my workaround was to define a udf and use python's type cast such as float(data) to do this. if the data is "uncastabe", an exception will be thrown

Comment: I want to cast string to date. If it is a date it will cast fine but if it isnt, lets say casting firstname column to date, then it results in null. I have read that UDFs arent really performant.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast a column to Integer type in following ways

`df.withColumn("hits", df("hits").cast("integer"))`

Or

```
data.withColumn("hitsTmp",
      data("hits").cast(IntegerType)).drop("hits").
      withColumnRenamed("hitsTmp", "hits")
```

Or

```
data.selectExpr ("user","topic","cast(hits as int) hits")
```

Comment: scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("hits", df("hits").cast("integer"))
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "hits" among
(user,  topic,  hits);
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(Dataset.scala:219)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(Dataset.scala:219)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolve(Dataset.scala:218)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.col(Dataset.scala:1073)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.apply(Dataset.scala:1059)
  ... 48 elided

Comment: scala> val df2 = df.selectExpr ("user","topic","cast(hits as int) hits")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`topic`' given input col
umns: [user,  topic,  hits]; line 1 pos 0;
'Project [user#0, 'topic, cast('hits as int) AS hits#40]
+- Relation[user#0, topic#1, hits#2] csv

Comment: can you do df.printSchema() before the line and paste the output?

Comment: scala> df.withColumn("hitsTmp",
     |       df("hits").cast(IntegerType)).drop("hits").
     |       withColumnRenamed("hitsTmp", "hits")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "hits" among
(user,  topic,  hits);
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(Dataset.scala:219)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(Dataset.scala:219)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolve(Dataset.scala:218)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.col(Dataset.scala:1073)
  ... 50 elided

Comment: scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |--  topic: string (nullable = true)
 |--  hits: string (nullable = true)

Comment: This is very strange

Comment: you mean the code where i loaded the data and tried the different options? or the lines you suggested?

Comment: val df = spark.read.options(Map("header"-> "true")).csv("path")

Comment: scala>    df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
    val dfNew = spark.sql("select *, cast('hist' as integer) as hist2 from test")

Comment: scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("hitsTmp",df.hits.cast(IntegerType)).drop("hits"
).withColumnRenamed("hitsTmp", "hits")

Comment: scala> val df2 = df.selectExpr ("user","topic","cast(hits as int) hits")

Comment: scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("hits", df("hits").cast("integer"))

Comment: scala> val df2 = df.selectExpr ("user","topic","cast(hits as int) hits")

Comment: scala> df.withColumn("hitsTmp",
      df("hits").cast(IntegerType)).drop("hits").
      withColumnRenamed("hitsTmp", "hits")

Comment: try this simple example 


    import spark.implicits._

    val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("om", "scaka", "120"),
      ("daniel", "spark", "80"),
      ("3754978", "spark", "1")
    )).toDF("user", "topic", "hits")

    data.withColumn("hits", $"hits".cast("integer")).printSchema()
    data.withColumn("hits", data("hits").cast("integer")).show

Comment: if I create the initial dataframe your way it works.....any idea of what it might be the problem?

Comment: Thanks by the way!!

Comment: So it wont work if you read from the file or something else ?

Comment: does it still shows the error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "hits" among (user, topic, hits) ??

Comment: creating the rows the way you suggested I have no problem, but I load the data from csv I get the error. I need to load csv files, so I'm wondering why is showing that error.

Comment: In case someone's wondering what exact `string` to pass for **type-name**, see how they've defined [`typeName`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.scala#L58) method and [`simpleString`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.scala#L73) method; where `simpleString` has been *overridden* at [certain places](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/IntegerType.scala#L46)

Answer (score 2):

I know that this answer probably won't be useful for the OP since it comes with a ~2 year delay. It might however be helpful for someone facing this problem.

Just like you, I had a dataframe with a column of strings which I was trying to cast to integer:

```
> df.show
+-------+
|     id|
+-------+
|4918088|
|4918111|
|4918154|
   ...

> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

But after doing the cast to `IntegerType` the only thing I obtained, just as you did, was a column of nulls:

```
> df.withColumn("test", $"id".cast(IntegerType))
    .select("id","test")
    .show
+-------+----+
|     id|test|
+-------+----+
|4918088|null|
|4918111|null|
|4918154|null|
      ...
```

By default if you try to cast a string that contain non-numeric characters to integer the cast of the column won't fail but those values will be set to `null` as you can see in the following example:

```
> val testDf = sc.parallelize(Seq(("1"), ("2"), ("3A") )).toDF("n_str")
> testDf.withColumn("n_int", $"n_str".cast(IntegerType))
        .select("n_str","n_int")
        .show
+-----+-----+
|n_str|n_int|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    1|
|    2|    2|
|   3A| null|
+-----+-----+
```

The thing with our initial dataframe is that, at first sight, when we use the `show` method, we can't see any non-numeric character. However, if you a row from your dataframe you'll see something different:

```
> df.first
org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [4?9?1?8?0?8?8??]
```

Why is this happening? You are probably reading a csv file containing a non-supported encoding.

You can solve this by changing the encoding of the file you are reading. If that is not an option you can also clean each column before doing the type cast. An example:

```
> val df_cast = df.withColumn("test", regexp_replace($"id", "[^0-9]","").cast(IntegerType))
                  .select("id","test")
> df_cast.show
+-------+-------+
|     id|   test|
+-------+-------+
|4918088|4918088|
|4918111|4918111|
|4918154|4918154|
       ...

> df_cast.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quote around `hist`
if that does not work, then
try trimming the column:

```
dfNew = spark.sql("select *, cast(trim(hist) as integer) as hist2 from test")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I was casting Strings to integers but I realized I needed to cast them to longs instead. It was hard to realize this at first since my column's type was an int when I tried to print the type using

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is delayed but i was facing the same issue & worked.So thought to put it over here. Might be of help to someone.
Try declaring the schema as StructType. Reading from CSV files & providing inferential schema using case class gives weird errors for data types. Although, all the data formats are properly specified.