# How to test datatype conversion during casting

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have a script that maps data into a dataframe (we're using pyspark).  The data comes in as a string, and some other sometimes expensive stuff is done to it, but as part of the operation (calling withColumn) we do a cast to it's final data type.

I have a requirement to tell if truncation occurred, but we don't want to fail if it does.  We just want a number to know how many rows in each translated column (there are about 300 columns) failed.

My first thought was to have each column pass through a UDF which would do the test, and the output would be an array with the value, and a value about if it passed the datatype checks.  I'd then do 2 selections.  One selects the raw values from the array, and the other aggregates the misses.  But this seems like a sloppy solution.  I'm fairly new to the pyspark/hadoop world... would love to know if there's a better (maybe standard?) way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the latest Spark versions casting numbers in Spark doesn't fail and doesn't result in silent overflows - if value is not properly formatted, or is to large to be accommodated by the target type, the result is undefined - `NULL`.

So all you have to do is simple count of `NULL` values ([Count number of non-NaN entries in each column of Spark dataframe with Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33900726/8371915)) after `cast`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import count

df = spark.createDataFrame(['132312312312312321312312', '123', '32'], 'string')
df_cast = df.withColumn('value_casted' , df['value'].cast('integer'))

df_cast.select((
    # count('value')         - count of NOT NULL values before
    # count('value_casted')  - count of NOT NULL values after
    count('value') - count('value_casted')).alias('value_failed')
).show()
# +------------+
# |value_failed|
# +------------+
# |           1|
# +------------+
```

Comment: This works for my purposes, I have no idea why I believed casting worked differently

Comment: Hi Alper, any better idea how to achieve the same without counting for nulls? Not really efficient if there are too many rows and columns each having to be casted.

Answer (score 0):

i think the udf solution is not a bad idea. it's exactly what i did:

```py
@udf(returnType=FloatType())
def float_cast(data):
    if data is not None:
        return float(data)


@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def int_cast(data):
    if data is not None:
        return int(data)

def cast_safe(data, _type):
    cast = {
        "float": float_cast,
        "int": int_cast,
    }
    return cast[_type](data)

df = df.withColumn(col_name, cast_safe(df[col_name], col_type))
```

Any possible exceptions will be triggered when materializing the df